# Automatic newline of a string when meet "|"

Tags: android

I have a String :  abcde|ghikml

I want when run application. It meet "|" .It will automatic newline.

Result:

abcde

ghikml

Please. Can you help me!

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far! But a replace function is probably the way to do it.

Comment: Simply use `String.replace()` to replace "|" with "\n".

Answer (score 0):

```
String mystring ="abcde|ghikml"
String[] divide = mystring.split("|");
separated[0]; // abcde
separated[1]; // ghikml
```

Comment: I have many similar string. I want write a class.
Please, Can you help me!

Answer (score 0):

```
String str1="abcde|ghikml";
String str2= str1.replace("|","\n");
```